# Angular JS with Ruby on Rails Routing Issues

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I'm trying to use Angular with Ruby on Rails. I'm wondering what the best way to do this would be. Currently I have a rails application that authenticates using Ruby. I however want the homepage of the site to be using Angular. How does this work with the controller and routes in angular? I want to use a CDN for using Angular (no gems for this).

This is what my angular routes look like:

```
var shopApp = angular.module('shopApp', ['ngRoute',        'shopControllers']);

shopApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
  when('/shop', {
    templateUrl: '../templates/shop.html',
    controller: 'ItemsController'
  }).
  when('/details/:itemId', {
    templateUrl: '../templates/details.html',
    controller: 'DetailsController'
  })
}]);
```

This is what my controllers look like:

```
var shopControllers = angular.module('shopControllers', []);
shopControllers.controller('ItemsController', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

}]);

shopControllers.controller('DetailsController', ['$scope','$http',  '$routeParams', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams,            $location) {

}]);
```

My question is: how is this supposed to work with the Ruby on Rails routes? if I do '/#/shop' shouldn't I be able to see the angular template view?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am also working on a personal project with rails 4 and angularjs. This tutorial helped me a lot http://blog.honeybadger.io/beginners-guide-to-angular-js-rails/.

Comment: You need to remember that your angular app is a single page app. So the routing in angular is just JS routing in angular's world, but from a rail's perspective it all happens on a single page. Therefor your rails routes should be setup to render a single page that references your angular app, and once you go there... angular should handle the rest.

Comment: Thanks guys. Yeah your posts really helped me. It turns out I needed a partials controller to match up with my view. Then I needed a route to go to for angular

Answer (score 0):

Create a route for the angular app in ruby on rails. This route will be the only route that ruby identifies with, but angular can use its own routing for pages within the single app.